# How to make Jenkins multibranch pipeline keep reusing the same build node for the same branch?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, incremental-build

Is the anyway to make a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline better support incremental builds by preferring the last build node when it build a branch instead of choosing an available node more or less randomly?

Details:

We are setting up a Jenkins multibranch pipeline for a large Git project, where we use Make to build and test a lot of code. A full build takes 6-8 hours, but the dependency tracking in Make is good enough for us to use incremental builds, shortening most our build times a lot. For this to work, Jenkins have to pick the same workspace for changes to the same branch again. Luckily it does so - but only on the same build node.

We have some identical Jenkins slave nodes available. Each time a build job is started due to a change on a branch in Git, Jenkins apparently pick a random free build node with a fresh, clean workspace meaning no incremental build speedup.

We have tried to build via NFS, such all the build nodes can share the workspaces, but at least the NFS server we have available is way too slow to make this work.

Is there anyway to make Jenkins choose the node a little less randomly and prefer the latest node on which the branch was build the last time?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: I created a bug report for it on Jenkins (JENKINS-51100). Someone posted some code to fix it, but it was unfortunately turned down in review. But going back to it now, it is marked as "Resolved". It seems that I have to find out if it is fixed in the newest version then.